# How to remove the html tags from output after retrieving from mysql select query?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I use htmlentities to process form data prior to inserting into db. When retrieving the data back out of the db, and outputing the data in my app the html tags appear.

How to perform my select query from mysql, and echo the data out without the html tags being present?

Example of my code:

```
<tr><th>Message: </th><td><?php echo $string; ?></td></tr>
```

Output on site:

```
 <br><br>Michael <br>Hotel Murray <br>1 Interstate Blvd. <br>Bluepoint, NJ 55555
```

---

Continued...

The output on the webpage still appears with the tags within it after using strip_tags. If i view the output using the edit page I built (which includes a WYSIWYG Editor) the output of the same text on the edit page within the WYSIWYG Editor box (prior to editing it) is correct (I mean - the html is actually being treated as html and the output or html is being formatted accordingly.). But if I just echo the string on the page without using the editor it keeps the tags and does not format it at all. please see:

CURRENTLY:

$string = $row['template_string'];

echo strip_tags($string);
echo "\n";

Output:

Michael 
Hotel Murray 
1 Interstate Blvd.  
Bluepoint, NJ 55555

TRYING TO END UP WITH:

$string = $row['template_string'];

echo strip_tags($string);
echo "\n";

Output:

Michael
Hotel Murray
1 Interstate Blvd.
Bluepoint, NJ 55555

Comment: [strip_tags](http://in3.php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: You wanna retrieve plain text by removing all html tags?

Comment: No - I have a form on my site that users enter data into. The form has a WYSIWYG Editor included for the template_string field. 

When users submit the form, the editor automatically creates the html based on the formatting the user did, the form then is inserted into a mysql db. 
THEN
When i do a select query to pull the data and publish it back onto the site, the output is including the html tags, with no formatting at all. I want it to be formatted exactly how the html tags would usually format it (but obviously i dont want the html tags to be visible on the site).

Comment: For example I want the output to look exactly like this post i submitted above. My main post/question I published above is formatting the post based on the html from the editor. That is all i need.

Comment: You should consider writing a proper [mcve] if you want to improve your question. Removing everything does not help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strip_tags function
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

[strip_tags](http://www.php.net/strip_tags%E2%80%8E) may be used for this purpose. You can also skip some tags that you do not want to be stripped off. Example code:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Comment: Please see above as I added to my original question/post. I added the result of strip_tags and some more info I am hoping will help lead us to a resolution.

Comment: if you are still facing the issue then can you please let me know what is the issue you are facing now. are tags not stripped of??

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to use html_entity_decode()

Thanks for the help though!